# Движущаяся метка Яндекс.Карты Api

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Задача каждые 30 секунд, обновлять координаты метки, и отображать их на карте, без перезагрузки.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  // Создание экземпляра карты.
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [50.443705, 30.530946],
      zoom: 14,
      type: "yandex#map",
      controls: ["smallMapDefaultSet", "trafficControl"]
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
  var fn2 = function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "coords.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
      objectManager.add(data);
    });

  }
  var intervalID = setTimeout(fn2, 300);
}
```

Метки не загружаются и не двигаются, как их загрузить, перезаписывать (обновлять) ?

Код метки

```
myPlacemark15318787 = new ymaps.Placemark([x, y], {
    hintContent: 'HD',
    balloonContent: 'HD'
}, {
    iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
    iconImageHref: 'images/hdb6.svg',
    iconImageSize: [30, 30],
    iconImageOffset: [-15, -15],
    iconContentOffset: [28, 1]
}),
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark15318787);
```

Comment: Хочу напомнить, что согласно условиям использования, цитирую: "При использовании бесплатной версии API нельзя:
Отслеживать транспорт, людей и другие объекты в реальном времени."

Comment: У нашей компании есть лицензия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете OM и всегда возвращаете все данные, которые должны быть отображены на карте, то нужно удалять OM с карты и добавлять его заново:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "coords.php"
}).done(function(data) {
  myMap.geoObjects.remove(objectManager);
  objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
  objectManager.add(data);
  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
});
```

Также нужно посмотреть, чтобы ваше приложение не нарушало условия использования https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/

Comment: Как вы думаете , оптимально ли использовать ОМ для данной задачи?

Comment: А если подробнее, то в чём состоит задача? Без подробного описания непонятно, что лучше использовать.

Comment: Каждые 30 секунд я получаю координаты с датчиков на своих машинах. Получает php скрипт и формирует json. Цель отображать на карте движущуюся машину. Про лицензию Яндекса я в курсе

Comment: неясно количество меток, но я бы сначала попробовал добавить на карту обычные метки и обновлять их координаты через placemark.geometry.setCoordinates() https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IPointGeometryAccess-docpage/#method_detail__setCoordinates Если бы этот вариант тормозил, то тогда бы уже искал другой путь

Comment: Не нашел ни одного примера placemark.geometry.setCoordinates() . Код метки указал в первом посте. Можете хоть набросок показать, в каком направлении идти

Comment: Ваш вопрос неясен.

Comment: хочу добавить, что 8 машин

Comment: Я просто не понимаю, что у вас не получается( Делаем запрос к серверу, получаем данные, добавляем количество меток на карту по количеству машин. Когда приходят новые данные, меняем координаты меток через placemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coordinates)

Comment: Не понимаю одного, ajax запросил коориднаты и id метки, как присвоить результат.  $.ajax({
      url: "coords.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
      return data;
    });

Comment: $.ajax({ url: "coords.php" }).done(function(data) {data.forEach((coords, index) => placemarks[index].geometry.setCoordinates(coords))}); Видимо как-то примерно так, но если предположить, что data это массив координат.

Comment: Все отлично с этим. У меня метки на карте в таком виде myPlacemark1, myPlacemark2, myPlacemark3 и тд. В цикле указываю myPlacemark+value.id.geometry.setCoordinates([value.lattitude, value.longitude]); ошибка undefined placemark

Comment: Пробовал myPlacemark[value.id].geometry.setCoordinates([value.lattitude, value.longitude]); то же самое

Comment: Это базовые знания js. Вы создаёте переменную, а обращаетесь к ней как будто она элемент массива. Почитайте больше про js https://learn.javascript.ru/array

Comment: делал конкатенация  myPlacemark+value.id.geometry.setCoordinates([value.lattitude, value.longitude]);  Все равно ошибка. Наверное я дурак и слабо понимаю что делаю.

Comment: Это отличный учебник learn.javascript.ru/array попробуйте его. Создайте метки через myPlacemarks = []; myPlacemarks.push(myPlacemark1);myPlacemarks.push(myPlacemark2);myPlacemarks.push(myPlacemark3); В цикле myPlacemarks[value.id].geometry.setCoordinates([value.lattitude, value.longitude]);